# Why is my Firebase updateProfile function not working in my React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get my sign-up form to work using `Firebase` `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and `updateProfile` functions in my React App. The sign-in function works (right panel), and I am able to see users in Firebase, however, when I try to create the displayName (left panel) I'm running into a reference issue.

My AuthContext provider has my signup function written like so:

```
export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
};

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const signup = (email, password) => {
    return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    signup,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {!loading && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I imported my useAuth function to my SignUp component and placed it inside my handleSubmit:

```
const { signup } = useAuth();
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (passwordRef.current.value !== passwordConfRef.current.value) {
      return setError("Please make sure passwords match.");
    }

    try {
      setError("");
      setLoading(true);

      const user = await signup(
        emailRef.current.value,
        passwordRef.current.value
      )

      await updateProfile(user, {
          displayName: usernameRef,
          uid: user.user.uid,
        })
      // console.log(user);
      navigate(`/dashboard/${user.user.uid}`);
    } catch (e) {
      setError("Something went wrong, please try again.");
      console.log(e.message)
    }

    setLoading(false);
  };
```

When the following console.log is run on the browser the following populates in the console: [image: app console error]

find the error below

> "Cannot access 'user' before initialization"

but I don't know what user reference it's referring to.

I read the following docs in reference to creating more login credentials for firebase:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#updateprofile
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/95

I originally had the updateProfie in a .then fucntion, however after some assistance I changed it await and now I'm getting a new error:

> userInternal.getIdToken is not a function

Answer (score 0):

The Promise chain isn't correct in the `handleSubmit` handler. The then-able should take a function instead of the result of ***immediately*** calling `updateProfile`. The `user` parameter likely hasn't been instantiated yet. In other words `updateProfile` is called when the component is rendered instead of when `handleSubmit` is called. You are also mixing the `async/await` and Promise-chain patterns. Use one or the other.

```js
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (passwordRef.current.value !== passwordConfRef.current.value) {
    setError("Please make sure passwords match.");
    return;
  }

  try {
    setError("");
    setLoading(true);

    await signup(
      emailRef.current.value,
      passwordRef.current.value,
    );

    navigate(`/dashboard/${user.user.id}`);
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn(e));
    setError("Something went wrong, please try again.");
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
};
```

You can call separately the `updateProfile` function when the `currentUser` state updates.

```
const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const signup = (email, password) => {
    return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser) {
      updateProfile({
        /* profile properties you want to update */
      });
    }
  }, [currentUser]);

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    signup,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {!loading && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: I did the following as you instructed and now it's throwing a new error: 

> TypeError: userInternal.getIdToken is not a function

I'm positive it's from the account_info.ts module within firebase. I read the docs provided @ https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User.

Comment: @skyeNoLimit Ah yeah, I see from the docs that [updateProfile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#updateprofile) is a `Promise<void>` return, meaning it doesn't return any `user` value. Is it the `currentUser` value from the `AuthProvider` you need to update/pass along to `updateProfile`? Can you clarify the use case or what the logical flow is to be here when signing in?

Comment: Yes EXACTLY! I do apologize for the vagueness of my question. I just wasn't sure where would be a good entry point for something like this. I want the currentUser to have a displayName. Google firebase only allows creation of users with email and password. However, you can add a displayName and picture, I just wasn't sure how.

Comment: @skyeNoLimit I see. You should probably move that logic into the the `AuthProvider` component to be called as an intentional side-effect when the `currentUser` state updates. I don't know where exactly `usernameRef` comes into play, so there may need to be some tweaking of the component code and logic.

Comment: Good idea, I will try later this evening and will keep you posted. Once again thank you so much for the helpful critiques in regards to question formatting and code assists